# Show/hide group of elements with conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

The code below does hides/shows if in the conditional rendering is only one element either label or text input but it doesn't work if I want to hide both elements. I need solution which will hide at least 2 or more elements.

```
 {trueMode === false && (<label htmlFor="car">Car</label> && 
                         <input onChange={handleChange} id="car" 
                                value={newVehicle.car} type="text" />)}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional rendering of multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68640091/conditional-rendering-of-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the elements with a fragment for example

```
{trueMode === false && (
  <>
    <label htmlFor="car">Car</label>
    <input onChange={handleChange} id="car" value={newVehicle.car} type="text" />
  </>
)}
```